# creating a window with no tabs that stays always visible on all spaces in Mac OS using swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

so I want to create something like loom where you have buttons on the left side of the screen and these buttons are always on top of any content and the stay visible even when you change the space by swiping with 3 finger .

as you can see in the attached image there is that floating window (Krisp)
and the stop recording button (Loom)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create your own `NSWindow`, because SwiftUI doesn't have API that lets you get the behavior you want. So you probably want to create your project using the Interface: Storyboard or Interface: XIB template setting, instead of the Interface: SwiftUI setting.

To make your window float above normal windows, set its [`level`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419511-level) property to [`.floating`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/level/1419352-floating).

To allow your window to join all Spaces, add [`.canJoinAllSpaces`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/collectionbehavior/1419246-canjoinallspaces) to its [`collectionBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419471-collectionbehavior) property. You may want to consider adding other behaviors like [`.auxiliary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/collectionbehavior/1419617-fullscreenauxiliary), [`.canJoinAllApplications`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/collectionbehavior/4097719-canjoinallapplications), and [`.stationary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/collectionbehavior/1419188-stationary).

Comment: I was able to use ```.collectionBehavior``` in my SiwftUi project  this way : 
```guard let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first else { assertionFailure(); return }
        window.collectionBehavior = .canJoinAllSpaces``` did in ```AppDelegate```  on ```applicationDidFinishLaunching``` .